# DataGrid Mui rows getting misaligned

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

as i scroll horizontally column data is getting shifted too.

[Ex: Here MRN/PATIENT ACCOUNT# value is ABC12345](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ9a4.png)

As i scroll horizontally to check the remaining columns

[Here MRN/PATIENT ACCOUNT#'s value(ABC12345) is under Payer Alias column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm30i.png)

As i scroll further horizontally

[Here MRN/PATIENT ACCOUNT#'s value(ABC12345) is under RenderingNpi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDzU8.png)

I am using DataGrid from Mui

```
                    <DataGrid
                        title='All Claims'
                        rows={claimTableData}
                        getRowId={(row)=>row.patient_eligibility_id}
                        columns={ELIGIBILITY_TABLE_COLUMNS}
                        rowsPerPageOptions={[]}
                        checkboxSelection
                        onSelectionModelChange={(newSelectionModal) => {
                            setSelectedData(newSelectionModal)
                        }}
                        components={{
                            Toolbar: customToolBar
                        }}
                        componentsProps={{
                            toolbar: { minHeight: '10px' }
                        }}
                        hideFooter
                    />

export const ELIGIBILITY_TABLE_COLUMNS = [
    {
        headerName: 'PATIENT FIRST NAME',
        field: 'first_name',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'PATIENT LAST NAME',
        field: 'last_name',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'DATE OF BIRTH',
        field: 'date_of_birth',
        width: 200,
        renderCell: (params) => (
            <span>
                {params.value && moment(params.value).isValid() ? moment(params.value).format('MM/DD/YYYY') : ''}
            </span>
        ),
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'FROM DATE OF SERVICE',
        field: 'from_date_of_service',
        width: 200,
        renderCell: (params) => (
            <span>
                {params.value && moment(params.value).isValid() ? moment(params.value).format('MM/DD/YYYY') : ''}
            </span>
        ),
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'TO DATE OF SERVICE',
        field: 'to_date_of_service',
        width: 200,
        renderCell: (params) => (
            <span>
                {params.value && moment(params.value).isValid() ? moment(params.value).format('MM/DD/YYYY') : ''}
            </span>
        ),
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'MRN/PATIENT ACCOUNT#',
        field: 'mrn_patient_account_no',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'PAYER ALIAS',
        field: 'payer_alias',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'SERVICE TYPE',
        field: 'service_type_id',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'MEMBER ID',
        field: 'member_id',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'RENDERING NPI',
        field: 'provider_npi',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'CLIENT ID',
        field: 'client_id',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'PAYER NAME',
        field: 'external_payer_name',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'EXTERNAL PAYER ID',
        field: 'payer_id',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'ELIGIBILITY STATUS',
        field: 'eligibility_status',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'GROUP NAME',// no value
        field: 'group_name',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'UPLOAD DATE',
        field: 'created_on',
        width: 200,
        renderCell: (params) => (
            <span>
                {params.value && moment(params.value).isValid() ? moment(params.value).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss') : ''}
            </span>
        ),
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'LAST VERIFIED',
        field: 'modified_on',
        width: 200,
        renderCell: (params) => (
            <span>
                {params.value && moment(params.value).isValid() ? moment(params.value).format('MM/DD/YYYY') : ''}
            </span>
        ),
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'PROCESSING STATUS',
        field: 'processing_status',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    },
    {
        headerName: 'COMMENTS/RESONS',
        field: 'comments',
        width: 200,
        align: 'left'
    }
 ]
```

Comment: What version of MUI you are using?

Comment: @mui/icons-material@5.8.0
│ └── @mui/material@5.8.0 deduped
├── @mui/material@5.8.0
└─┬ @mui/x-data-grid@5.11.1
  └── @mui/material@5.8.0 deduped
@Aryclenio